# Raphael js, how to get a circle's center x, y position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

If I have a circle object

`var c = paper.circle(...)`

I would like to get this circle's center x, y position, how to get?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get the SVG attributes of `cx` and `cy` with:

```
c.attr('cx');
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like:

```
var c = paper.circle(...);
var centerX = c.attr('x') + c.attr('width') / 2;
var centerY = c.attr('y') + c.attr('height') / 2;
```